# Why do I get "does not live long enough" errors when reimplementing C++ signals & slots in Rust?

Tags: rust, signals-slots

As a learning exercise, I've been translating a fairly standard C++ signal implementation into Rust:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

trait Notifiable<E> {
    fn notify(&self, e: &E);
}

struct SignalData<'l, E>
where
    E: 'l,
{
    listeners: BTreeMap<usize, &'l Notifiable<E>>,
}

struct Signal<'l, E>
where
    E: 'l,
{
    next_id: usize,
    data: Rc<RefCell<SignalData<'l, E>>>,
}

struct Connection<'l, E>
where
    E: 'l,
{
    id: usize,
    data: Weak<RefCell<SignalData<'l, E>>>,
}

impl<'l, E> Signal<'l, E>
where
    E: 'l,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            next_id: 1,
            data: Rc::new(RefCell::new(SignalData {
                listeners: BTreeMap::new(),
            })),
        }
    }

    pub fn connect(&mut self, l: &'l Notifiable<E>) -> Connection<'l, E> {
        let id = self.get_next_id();
        self.data.borrow_mut().listeners.insert(id, l);
        Connection {
            id: id,
            data: Rc::downgrade(&self.data),
        }
    }

    pub fn disconnect(&mut self, connection: &mut Connection<'l, E>) {
        self.data.borrow_mut().listeners.remove(&connection.id);
        connection.data = Weak::new();
    }

    pub fn is_connected_to(&self, connection: &Connection<'l, E>) -> bool {
        match connection.data.upgrade() {
            Some(data) => Rc::ptr_eq(&data, &self.data),
            None => false,
        }
    }

    pub fn clear(&mut self) {
        self.data.borrow_mut().listeners.clear();
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.data.borrow().listeners.is_empty()
    }

    pub fn notify(&self, e: &E) {
        for (_, l) in &self.data.borrow().listeners {
            l.notify(e);
        }
    }

    fn get_next_id(&mut self) -> usize {
        let id = self.next_id;
        self.next_id += 1;
        id
    }
}

impl<'l, E> Connection<'l, E>
where
    E: 'l,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Connection {
            id: 0,
            data: Weak::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn is_connected(&self) -> bool {
        match self.data.upgrade() {
            Some(_) => true,
            None => false,
        }
    }

    pub fn disconnect(&mut self) {
        match self.data.upgrade() {
            Some(data) => {
                data.borrow_mut().listeners.remove(&self.id);
                self.data = Weak::new();
            }
            None => (),
        }
    }
}

impl<'l, E> Drop for Connection<'l, E>
where
    E: 'l,
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.disconnect();
    }
}
```

This compiles and behaves as expected for simple test code:

```
struct Event {}
struct Listener {}

impl Notifiable<Event> for Listener {
    fn notify(&self, _e: &Event) {
        println!("1: event");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let l1 = Listener {};
    let l2 = Listener {};
    let mut s = Signal::<Event>::new();
    let c1 = s.connect(&l1);
    let mut c2 = s.connect(&l2);

    println!("c2: {}", c2.is_connected());
    s.disconnect(&mut c2);
    println!("c2: {}", c2.is_connected());

    let e = Event {};
    s.notify(&e);

    println!("done!");
}
```

However, if I try something more similar to the envisaged use case, it doesn't compile:

```
struct Event {}
struct System<'l> {
    signal: Signal<'l, Event>,
}
struct Listener<'l> {
    connection: Connection<'l, Event>,
}

impl<'l> Notifiable<Event> for Listener<'l> {
    fn notify(&self, _e: &Event) {
        println!("1: event");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut listener = Listener {
        connection: Connection::new(),
    };
    let mut system = System {
        signal: Signal::new(),
    };

    listener.connection = system.signal.connect(&listener);

    println!("is_connected(): {}", listener.connection.is_connected());
    system.signal.disconnect(&mut listener.connection);
    println!("is_connected(): {}", listener.connection.is_connected());

    let e = Event {};
    system.signal.notify(&e);

    println!("done!");
}
```

Which gives the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `listener` does not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:147:50
    |
147 |     listener.connection = system.signal.connect(&listener);
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
157 | }
    | - `listener` dropped here while still borrowed
    |
    = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

It seems that my problems stem from `SignalData`, where I store the collection of listeners as references: `listeners: BTreeMap<usize, &'l Notifiable<E>>`. That lifetime requirement seems to propagate ever outwards.

The purpose of the `Connection` class (at least in C++) is to allow disconnection from the `Listener` end, and manage the lifetime of the connection, removing the `Listener` entry from the signal when it goes out of scope.

The lifetime of the `Connection` must be less than or equal to that of both the `Signal` and the relevant `Listener`. However, the lifetime of the `Listener` and `Signal` should otherwise be entirely independent.

Is there a way to alter my implementation to achieve this, or is it fundamentally broken?

Comment: Unrelated, but for idiomatic code: `if let` instead of a `match` with one arm, `Option::is_some()`, and `Option::map_or`. These will shorten your implementations

Comment: Did you use a reference in C++, or did you use a smart-pointer?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well, technically a `std::function`... (which would in turn store a reference to `*this` I guess). I did try to use `Fn` initially, but had problems with it.

Comment: Compiling with nightly and `#![feature(nll)]` gives a somewhat better error message.

Comment: @user673679: I see; then you probably have a lifetime issue in C++ and never realized it :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Not really. Or at least... it's for the code supplying the `std::function` to ensure that the move / copy semantics  and lifetimes of whatever is stored in the `std::function` are correct, not for the signal / connection code.

Comment: (I see now that my immediate issues above can be solved by putting the listener in an `Rc<RefCell<Listener>>`, and then storing a `Weak<RefCell<Notifiable<E>>>`, but I don't like the way it forces all listeners to suddenly be shared pointers on the heap... I think there's probably a cleaner way).

Comment: @user673679: Rust won't stand for "it's up to the caller to", unless the function is marked `unsafe`. This makes implementing observers trickier... but safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals/Slots are complicated. *Really complicated*.

In C++, you can use [`Boost.Signals`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/signals.html), a library crafted by C++ experts which... ah wait no. Despite their expertise, the authors of Boost.Signals didn't manage to make it thread-safe, you should use [`Boost.Signals2`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/signals2.html) instead.

Chances are, your homegrown C++ implementation requires care to use, lest it invokes undefined behavior.

A straightforward port of such a library will not work in Rust. The goal of Rust is to be upfront about undefined behavior: you have to clearly mark unsafe code as... `unsafe`.

---

In fine, a Signals/Slots implementation is akin to an Observer, and an Observer traditionally requires a *cyclic ownership*. This works well in Garbage Collected languages, but requires more forethought when memory is managed manually.

The most straightforward, and error-prone, solution is to use a pair of `Rc`/`Weak` (or `Arc`/`Weak` for multi-threaded code). It is up to the developer to strategically place `Weak` pointers to break the cycles (lest they leak).

In Rust, there is another hurdle: cyclic ownership implies *aliasing*. By default, Rust requires that aliased content be immutable which is quite limiting. To regain mutability, you will need *interior mutability*, either with `Cell` or `RefCell` (or `Mutex` for multi-threaded code).

The good news: despite all the intricacies, if your code compile it will be safe (though it may still leak).

---

Another solution, to avoid all the heap allocations inherent to such a design, is to move toward a message-passing scheme instead. Instead of directly invoking a method on an object, you can send a message to an object via its ID. A difficulty of this scheme is that messages are asynchronous, so the method called can only communicate a result by sending a message back.

[Citybound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qr9GTTST_Dk) is a game developed in Rust using fine-grained actors communicating with such a scheme. There is also the [`actix`](https://github.com/actix/actix) actor framework, which has been quite finely tuned performance wise as can be seen on the TechEmpower benchmarks (placed 7 in [Round 15](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r15&hw=ph&test=plaintext)).